Do I need to take the outershell of eucalyptus to build a table?
I was lucky enough to get a "disk/segment" of a centenary eucalyptus.
I would like to make a rustic table of this "disk". The wood is completly dry and ready to be worked. I will level it, sand it an apply a neutral varnish.
I love the outershell effect on the disk, but it's very soft. I think it will be a mistake to leave it. I would like to have an expert opinion. Can I keep it? If yes, what type of care should I gjve it?


Did you do any research on the issue of leaving bark on wood where it's still in place? There is plenty of back and forth debate about whether one can safely do this on live-edge pieces and on slices or "cookies".

I recently completed a similar project with a slice of cypress 5-6cm thick x 60-80 cm wide and 18 months drying in less than optimal conditions (on my front verandah). The slab had very interesting wood grub tracks in the outer layer of the timber, under the bark but only in the conducting tissue of the xylem, no deeper. I ended up removing all the bark as it was drying off in thick chunks and couldn't see a way to stop it flaking away.
I'm no dendrologist, but the bark texture suggests the timber is a "stringybark" species.  I would suspect that even if you fixed the fibres with glue or varnish it might still crumble after a few months. Even simple wear-and-tear (coffee mugs, pets, etc) might crack whatever fixatives you could apply.
Perhaps you could experiment with acrylic resins to see if you can lock the bark in place, a bit like those scientific specimens of insects or flowers from high school practicals. It would have to be really "clean" so you didn't get fibres all over the top surface. Getting the air bubbles out from the cracks between the timber and the bark layer would also be a task and a half. (Don't use the piece in the photograph until you know what you're doing!).

You are right on the spot. The outershell is "stringybark". And The part in the photo is actually the part in best condition. To make this work I would have to fixate it somehow as you suggest. Thank you.
